# Reference request on non-Hausdorff topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am looking for a introductory textbook dedicated to non-Hausdorff topology, covering how standard definitions and concepts can be adapted to that case. That would be great if the book could include examples and assignments. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a textbook which deals with topological spaces which need not be Hausdorff, or specifically about those topologies which are non-Hausdorff? In the first case, there are some really good textbooks on general topology which deal with a very general case. Munkres *Topology*, Dugundji *Topology*, Kelley *General Topology* and many more. As for a book which deals explicitly with non-Hausdorff topologies, I am not so sure; this does not seem like a natural thing to study.

Comment: Most (all?) of the standard general topology texts do this. Besides the books that SamM listed, see: Császár's **Foundations of General Topology** (1963), Cullen's **Introduction to General Topology** (1968), Engelking's **General Topology** (1989), Wilansky's **Topology for Analysis** (1970), Willard's **General Topology** (1970). If you're really seeking generality (in a book), see Cech's **Topological Spaces** (1966), which does everything in the setting of his "closure spaces", which are a generalization of the notion of a topological space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these suggestions. I am interested in books that make the differences between Hausdorff and non-Hausdorff topologies explicit in order to help me understand what tools and results rely on this property. I will have a look at your references. Thank you!